Calculate week based on Settings
We have configuration in system where Admin can set Start month of Year and Start Day of the week.
Based on this , I need to calculate the Week and Month the Date falls in that Year.
Ex: If start month is April and Start Day of Week Wednesday.
Date -> 18/April/2024 -> will be in 4th week
Explanation:

1/April/2024 is Monday and 2/April/2024 is Tuesday -> this is first week
3/April to 9/April - > 2nd week
10/April to 16/April -> 3rd week
17/April to 23/April -> 4th week

So 18/April falls in 4th week of Year 1/April/2024 to 31/March/2025
Month value is 1
Month of the Year can be calculated as below
where StartingMonth is of type MonthOfYear and is set based on Configuration , April for above example.
public int GetMonthOfYear(DateTime Date)
{
   if((int)this.startingMonth < 0 || (int)this.startingMonth > 12) return 0;
   return (Date.Month - (int)this.startingMonth);
}

Is there any built in way to calculate week part in .NET for doing this?
I have searched on google but to no avail. This answers for week in month - Get week of month C# [duplicate] but not for year

Nothing build in but some 3rd party may have something  but just like with week of year it depends on your definition what first week is. For week of year there are multiple well known standards. I doubt there is one for week of month so if some one has something its presumably not fitting to your definition.
